# OpenCV-based wrapper for Windows screen capture

Tags: c++, performance, windows, winapi, opencv

I have written a `ScreenVideoCapture` class that implements an interface for capturing frames from a specified monitor connected to the PC. It uses OpenCV structures (including a `cv::Mat` for image output) and implements the core of the methods that OpenCV's `VideoCapture` has so that they can be used mostly interchangeably.

The class's constructor/`open` method take an index that corresponds to the target monitor. It uses the Win32 API to find the proper target rectangle, and then captures from that rectangle when the `read` method or `>>` operator are used. Credit goes to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148758/how-to-capture-the-desktop-in-opencv-ie-turn-a-bitmap-into-a-mat) for the basis of the capture code, although it has been modified.

#### Specific points of interest:

- Could I structure my class in a way that made it more interchangeable with OpenCV's `VideoCapture`? Currently, it can be used in the same way as the `VideoCapture`, but it must be `ifdef`-ed in in place of the alternative or called separately. There is no way of swapping the implementation at runtime.
- Is there a better way of specifying the target monitor that isn't reliant on the order that `EnumDisplayMonitors` uses? I remember reading docs that said that the order was constant and determined based on resolution, but I can no longer find that page.
- Can I make the capture more efficient? I am reallocating buffers on each call and do a fair amount of copying from one location to another, but I am not completely sure of what can be done once and what must be done every time.

**ScreenVideoCapture.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>

class ScreenVideoCapture
{
public:
    ScreenVideoCapture(int displayIndex = -1);
    ~ScreenVideoCapture();

    void open(int displayIndex);
    void read(cv::Mat& destination);
    ScreenVideoCapture& operator>>(cv::Mat& destination);

private:
    cv::Rect2d captureArea;
    HWND targetWindow = NULL;


    void captureHwnd(HWND window, cv::Rect2d targetArea, cv::Mat& dest);
    static BOOL CALLBACK monitorEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData);
};

struct MonitorIndexLookupInfo
{
    int targetIndex;

    RECT outRect;
    int currentIndex;
};
```

**ScreenVideoCapture.cpp:**

```
#include "ScreenVideoCapture.h"

ScreenVideoCapture::ScreenVideoCapture(int displayIndex)
{
    if (displayIndex >= 0)
        open(displayIndex);
}

void ScreenVideoCapture::open(int displayIndex)
{
    MonitorIndexLookupInfo enumState = { displayIndex, NULL, 0 };
    EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, monitorEnumProc, (LPARAM) &enumState);

    this->captureArea = cv::Rect2d(enumState.outRect.left, enumState.outRect.top, enumState.outRect.right - enumState.outRect.left, enumState.outRect.bottom - enumState.outRect.top);
    this->targetWindow = GetDesktopWindow();
}

BOOL CALLBACK ScreenVideoCapture::monitorEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
{
    MonitorIndexLookupInfo* enumState = (MonitorIndexLookupInfo*)dwData;
    if (enumState->targetIndex == enumState->currentIndex)
    {
        enumState->outRect = *lprcMonitor;
        return false;
    }

    enumState->currentIndex++;

}

ScreenVideoCapture::~ScreenVideoCapture()
{
}

void ScreenVideoCapture::read(cv::Mat& destination)
{
    if (targetWindow == NULL)
        throw new std::exception("No target monitor specified! The 'open()' method must be called to select a target monitor before frames can be read.");

    captureHwnd(targetWindow, captureArea, destination);
}

ScreenVideoCapture& ScreenVideoCapture::operator>>(cv::Mat& destination)
{
    read(destination);
    return *this;
}

void ScreenVideoCapture::captureHwnd(HWND window, cv::Rect2d targetArea, cv::Mat& dest)
{
    HDC hwindowDC, hwindowCompatibleDC;

    HBITMAP hbwindow;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER  bi;

    hwindowDC = GetDC(window);
    hwindowCompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hwindowDC);
    SetStretchBltMode(hwindowCompatibleDC, COLORONCOLOR);

    dest.create(targetArea.height, targetArea.width, CV_8UC4);

    // Initialize a bitmap
    hbwindow = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hwindowDC, targetArea.width, targetArea.height);
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth = targetArea.width;
    // The negative height is required -- removing the inversion will make the image appear upside-down.
    bi.biHeight = -targetArea.height;
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow);
    // Copy from the window device context to the bitmap device context
    // Use BitBlt to do a copy without any stretching -- the output is of the same dimensions as the target area.
    BitBlt(hwindowCompatibleDC, 0, 0, targetArea.width, targetArea.height, hwindowDC, targetArea.x, targetArea.y, SRCCOPY);
    // Copy into our own buffer as device-independent bitmap
    GetDIBits(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow, 0, targetArea.height, dest.data, (BITMAPINFO *) &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    // Clean up memory to avoid leaks
    DeleteObject(hbwindow);
    DeleteDC(hwindowCompatibleDC);
    ReleaseDC(window, hwindowDC);
}
```

Comment: How many fps at what resolution were you able to achieve?